# Need img:hover to not affect layout

Tags: html, css

I have a gallery, that when on hover it blows up the image.  It currently enlarges the image, but messes with the layout of the rest of the page.  Is there a way to have the image enlarge and not mess with the remaining images?

here is the css

```
.gimg{
    height:85px;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.gimg:hover{
    height:170px;
    width:300px;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the CSS3 property `transform: scale(n)` instead:

```
.gimg:hover{
    transform: scale(2);     // You might want to add vendor
    transform-origin: 0 0;   // prefixes to these properties
}
```

Note: If you don't want the image to expand centrally (transform origin in the smack middle), you might want to specify the transform origin:

```
transform-origin: posx posy;
```

In this case I would recommend using `transform-origin: 0 0;` since you are floating your image to the left.

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/t3rUb/ (vendor prefixes have been added)

**[Edit]:** With regards to concern with a blurry image, if you are using a higher resolution than the image is going to expand to, you do not have to worry about reduced resolution.

Comment: @minitech Not if the image is scaled down to begin with.

Comment: @minitech Check the updated fiddle. I am using Chrome, and it is not scaling up the downsampled image. It is scaling up the source image properly.

Comment: @Kolink: Apparently “last time I checked” was a while ago :P

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the margin appropriately:

```css
.gimg {
    height: 85px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.gimg:hover {
    height: 170px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: -32px -65px -32px -65px;
}
```